# Java error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, expression

I am taking my first java course and am writing a program that calculates income tax. I am getting 3 identical errors that say "illegal start of expression" and point to the asterisks in the following code. I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake but I'm not sure what to fix!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab02
{
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int exemptions; // Number of Exemptions
    double grossSalary; // Gross Salary
    double interestIncome; // Interest Income
    double capitalGains; // Capital Gains
    double charitableCont; // Charitable Contributions

    double totalIncome; // Total Income
    double adjustedIncome; // Adjusted Income
    double totalTax; // Total Tax


    System.out.print( "Number of Exemptions: ");
    exemptions = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print( "Gross Salary: ");
    grossSalary = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print( "Interest Income: ");
    interestIncome = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print( "Capital Gains: ");
    capitalGains = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print( "Charitable Contributions: ");
    charitableCont = input.nextDouble();


    totalIncome = (grossSalary + interestIncome);

    adjustedIncome = (totalIncome - (exemptions * 1500.00) - charitableCont);


    if (adjustedIncome <= 10000)
        totalTax0 = 0;

        if (adjustedIncome > 10000)
            totalTax1 = 15% * ( adjustedIncome >= 32000 ? (22000) : (adjustedIncome - 10000) );

            if (adjustedIncome > 32000)
                totalTax2 = 23% * (adjustedIncome >= 50000 ? (18000) : (adjustedIncome - 32000) );

                if (adjustedIncome > 50000)
                    totalTax3 = 28% * (adjustedIncome - 50000);

    totalTax = totalTax0 + totaltax1 + totaltax2 + totaltax3;


    System.out.printf( "Total Income: $%.2f%n", totalIncome ); // display Total Income
    System.out.printf( "Adjusted Income: $%.2f%n", adjustedIncome ); // display Adjusted Income
    System.out.printf( "Total Tax: $%.2f%n", totalTax ); // display Total Tax

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, there are no `totalTax[0-3]` variables declared anywhere, you'll need to either declare them or rewrite the logic.

Comment: Your `if` statements are nested, as if you believe they are nested inside each other, but there are no braces `{}`, so they are *not* nested, and your indentations are misleading, and will cause code errors in the future when modifications need to be made. Indentations should always reflect the code structure, so that humans and the Java compiler sees the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no percent operator, `%`, in Java. Java considers `%` as a remainder (somewhat like a modulus) operator, and it doesn't work the way you think.

So do `0.15` or `15.0 / 100`, or something similar instead of `15%`

e.g., this:

```
totalTax1 = 15% * ( adjustedIncome >= 32000 ? (22000) : (adjustedIncome - 10000) );
```

becomes

```
totalTax1 = 0.15 * ( adjustedIncome >= 32000 ? (22000) : (adjustedIncome - 10000) );
```

Comment: @SteeleDesmond: you're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

It was a simple mistake. I was using the modulus operator as a percentage sign.

Comment: Please delete this, as there already is a correct answer for your question. Please have a look at [help] section to see how this site works.